# Using WSO2 IS to create a circle of trust among Service Providers

Tags: authentication, dns, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I have various applications registered as Service Providers on WSO2. I want to keep WSO2 IS as the IdP, but have different circles of trust among the service providers. Is there any way in the management console to set these trust circles?

Comment: Can you explain a use case of the circle of trust among the service providers? Then we clearly understand the requirement

Comment: The use case is that I am trying to use WSO2 IS as an IdP for around 20-30 applications which will have SSO capabilities with different applications. For example 5 of those applications will all have a circle of trust with WSO2, thus when you log into one you have access to the other 4, but not any of the other applications. I am trying to figure out how WSO2 IS configures the circle of trust with its service providers.

Comment: there is no such a feature out of the box unless you made heavy customization to authentication . framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server does not have an out of the box solution or feature to group service providers and create a circle of trust.

However, if you based on your explanation in the comments it seems like you want to enable SSO among only the service providers within the circle of trust. Please check out this [blog](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/11/24/service-provider-grouping-with-wso2-identity-server/) which explains a possible solution to achieve this.

The basic idea of the solution is that applications within different circles(of trust) will access the WSO2 Identity Server using unique hostnames. For example, circle "abc" one can access the IDP with hostname abc.idp.com and another circle "xyz" can access the same IDP with xyz.idp.com hostname. Since the cookie that facilitates SSO will be set against the hostname of the IDP, the Single Sign-On feature will only work among service providers belonging to the same circle of trust.